# bootstrap.php.cache is missing

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans-8

I have a problem with Symfony 2.  trying the example from the book. I have written a controller but when i go to the URL specified in the route i get an error. The server  can't find the page.  When i run app_dev.php i get an error that the file boostrap.php.cache is missing.

searched on the internet but found nothing relevant so far. I don't know if the front-controller is already written or if that is something that still has to be done by me.

I can't get the application to run.

Comment: How did you install Symfony?

Comment: Have you done composer install?

Comment: I installed via netbeans. Also composer is installed :"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" "--ansi" "--no-interaction" "install" "--dev"
You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Done.

Comment: What installation steps did you use? Did you keep close to the installation guide in the book? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: downloaded zip file(2.7) Created a new project. With symfony2, doctrine2 and Composer framework installed via Tools -> Options -> PHP -> tab frameworks & tools . in Netbeans.

Comment: followed the instuctions in the book and copied the project into my netbeans project. Then i deleted the old netbeans project. Still no difference.  File not found. But the file is now present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I followed the guidelines installing sf2 in netbeans. Instead of running the application as a local website i used the build-in server option wich gave me access to the cli commands. There i could use the command run server and all of my problems were gone.